# What is the purpose of this clear_mem function?

Tags: c, memory

I've been trying to work out exactly what this function's purpose is I've come across..
The code intentionally has bad code practices, so I am trying to figure out if this is one of them.

Here is the function:

```
void clear_mem(char *memblock, int siz) {
  register int i;

  for (i=0; i<=siz;i++)
      *(memblock+i) = 0;

}
```

The function is called within the following function:

```
char *get_argument(char line[], int argno){
    char *argument = malloc(512);
    char clone[512];
    strncpy(clone, line, strlen(line)+1);

    int current_arg = 0;
    char *splitted = strtok(clone, " ");
    while (splitted != NULL){
        if (splitted[0] != ':'){
            current_arg++;
        }
        if (current_arg == argno+1){
            clear_mem(argument, 512); //Here
            strncpy(argument, splitted, strlen(splitted)+1);
            return argument;
            free(argument);
        }
        splitted = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    if (current_arg != argno){
        argument[0] = '\0';
    }
    free(argument);
    return argument;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It "clears the memory" - sets 513 (!) bytes starting from address `argument` to zero.

Comment: The use of `<=` seems to be a bug. It's likely that it shall be just `<`

Comment: It's not "bad coding practice" what you hacve here in `clear_mem`, it's worse, it's a bug.

Comment: Where is the line between really bad practice and a bug? ;)

Comment: Looking at the code, I suspect saying it “intentionally has bad code practices” is not completely accurate. It looks more like code created to quiz students for errors in the code. If you want help understanding a homework assignment, you can just ask about a specific problem in it you have having trouble with.

Comment: @Gerhardh you can write a terrible program full of gotos, magic numbers and other things that make your code unreadable and difficult to maintain (IOW full of "bad coding practice"), but it might still be bug free.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, but this program is full of bugs.

Comment: Notably, although `clear_mem` is pointless before `strncpy`, that is not an uncommon mistake among beginners, but the `return argument; free(argument);` in one place and `free(argument); return argument;` in another smack of the sort of intentional errors that would be planted in a quiz.

Comment: I didn't check in detail, but the usage of `strncpy` also looks fishy here. Actually using `strncpy` is almost always fishy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil and it is wrong in both places

Comment: @Gerhardh: That is not the point of my statements. The issue is not whether the code is right or wrong. The issue is how the statements illuminate the intent of the author. These examples do not look like mistakes. They look like intentional errors. Where does one write intentional errors? In quizzes or homework assignments where the student is asked to find the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
for (i=0; i<=siz;i++)
      *(memblock+i) = 0;
```

`memblock+i` adds the integer `i` to the pointer `memblock`. The result points `i` elements beyond where `memblock` points. Since `memblock` is a pointer to `char`, the result points `i` characters beyond where `memblock` points.

Then `*(memblock+i)` refers to the character at that address. `*(memblock+i)` is equivalent to `memblock[i]`. `*(memblock+i) = 0` sets the character to zero.

So the effect of this code is to set all characters indexed by `i` during the loop to zero. It clears a block of memory.

The `for (i=0; i<=siz;i++)` causes the loop to iterate with `i` taking all values from zero up to and including `siz`. Thus, `siz`+1 characters will be set to zero.

We can see this is an error because `get_argument` allocates 512 bytes for `argument` and then later calls `clear_mem(argument, 512)`, which clears 513 bytes. The resulting behavior is not defined by the C code.